# Prove that this set is a Baire second category set

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces, baire-category

Let $A$ be a Baire second category subset in metric space $\mathbb{R}$ with metric $\rho{(x, y)} = |x-y|$, $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$.
It is necessary to show that $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$ the set $x + A = \{x+a: a \in A\}$ is also a Baire second category set in $(\mathbb{R}, \rho)$.

My idea was to show that this set is a complete metric space, which as far as I know automatically implies that it's a Baire second category set, but I am not sure how to prove that either.

In general, this is the first time I have encountered any problems involving Baire categories so I would highly appreciate it if someone could suggest a common approach to such problems.

The formulation of the problem doesn't sound complicated, but I can't see what this $x + A = \{x+a: a \in A\}$ set gives us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(y)=x+y$ is a  homeomorphism so it presreves all topological notions: it preserves open sets, closed sets, closures, interiors etc. It maps nowhere dense sets to nowhere dense sets. Just apply the definition of  second category set to finish the proof.

Comment: "A Baire second category set is one which contains a countable union of open and dense sets"

Given that $x+y$ is a homeomorphism, it is indeed a matter of citing the definition to show that the new set is also a Baire second category theorem. 

I am not sure that we ever used the notion of homeomorphism in our course. How do I show that $x+y$ is a homeomorphism or probably there is another way to say the same?

Comment: Inverse of $f$ is $g(y)=y-x$. Can you see that $f$ and $g$ are both continuous? @DonDraper

Comment: Yes, I can. Given that both functions are continuous we can infer that this is a homeomorphism.

Answer (score 0):

If $S\subset \Bbb R$ and $x\in\Bbb R$ then int $(\,(-x)+\overline S\,)=$int($\;\overline {(-x)+S}\;).$

If $x+A$ is 1st category then $x+A=\cup F$ where $F$ is countable and int ($\overline S)=\emptyset$ for each $S\in F,$ implying that $A=\cup \{(-x)+S:S\in F\}$ is also the union of a countable family of nowhere-dense sets.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I don't understand though, is your proof more general in that it proves that this function preserves categories? 
UPD: Sorry, I understood the idea now.

Comment: Should it be for each $S \subset F$?

Comment: No. $S\in F$...... $F$ is a collection of subsets of $\Bbb R$ and $A$ is their common union.